# UIScrollView delegate functions skipped when scrolling fast

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I’m using the scrollView delegate functions to determine when data should be loaded and visual updates should be made on a collectionView with paging enabled (e.g. `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)`.

However, when scrolling though the pages very fast, the delegate functions are skipped sometimes.

Are there any functions that will never be skipped? Or better yet, how to ensure that the standard delegate functions will be called on each scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollViewDidScroll`, never skipped, but you need to calculate each page with the current `origin.y` (or `x` if scroll is not vertical) of your `scrollView`.

Comment: ScrollView did scroll is an option, but it is called incredibly often. I was hoping that there was a function that gets called (close to) one time per scroll to not create too much inefficiency

Comment: Unfortunately I had some trouble with paging enabled on scrollView before and the only way never failed was using didScroll.. your can try with scrollViewWillEndDragging use scrollViewDidEndDragging to improve chances ?

Comment: I don’t know whether that would enhance the chance but even if it did, I need something reliable that works all of the time. Did scroll is something I really would not like to mess with, because of performance concerns but also because I have to manually calculate the page every time... but I guess it will have to do if there is no better option. Anyway, thank you for your help!